# The Conditional (Ternary) Operator is not working as expected(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, neo4j, conditional-statements

I have this condition and I expect to see the result based on the `userId` and `name` (If `userId` presented search based on `userId` and if name presented search based on the name), but what I'm receiving is that is always returning the `else` and is not considering the `userId`

```
function findUsers(userId, name, skip, limit) {
  let queryString = (userId) ?
    'MATCH (user:User {userId:{userId}}) ' :
    'MATCH (user:User) ' +
    'WHERE ((user.username =~ {name}) OR (user.name =~ {name})) ' +
    'WITH user ' +
    'ORDER BY user.name ' +
    'RETURN DISTINCT user.userId, user.username, user.name ' +
    'SKIP {skip} LIMIT {limit}';

  let cypher = {
    query: queryString,
    params: {
      userId: userId,
      name: util.format('(?i).*%s.*', name),
      skip: skip,
      limit: limit
    }
  };
```

Comment: So... what is the value of `userId`?

Comment: The value of **userId** and **name** coming from front-end and both are **string**

Comment: I think you miss my question - "are string" is not "value"... Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code one more time more carefully - you need to provide all information inline in the post.

Comment: If the value of `userId` is one of the following: `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `''` (empty string), then it is considered falsey and your ternary will return the false half of the ternary, otherwise, any defined, non-empty string will resolve as truthy. Do you know the value of `userId`?

Comment: For example for one sample I have **d60a9702-8f2c-4298-843c-ac8686c5968f** for the value of **userId** and it's not undefined, null, false, ' '

Comment: It works correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/q72wavcp/2/

Comment: @Barmar Yes thank you, but I think I'm missing the return in the program to work as I expected

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you, I'll try to do so

Comment: @Nafis What does `return` have to do with it? Isn't your problem that you're putting the wrong `queryString` in `cypher`?

Comment: BTW, is it intentional that you only use `skip` and `limit` in the `name` query rather than `userID`? You may need some parentheses to split those out of the ternary.

Comment: @Barmar I found that because I don't have the `Return` for the first `MATCH` it cannot return anything, yes I should have `skip` and `limit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ternary has lower precedence than `+`, so all the concatenations are being put into the `else` part. Use parentheses to so that you juse select the appropriate `MATCH` option based on the ternary.

```
  let queryString = (
        (userId) ?
        'MATCH (user:User {userId:{userId}}) ' :
        'MATCH (user:User) ') +
    'WHERE ((user.username =~ {name}) OR (user.name =~ {name})) ' +
    'WITH user ' +
    'ORDER BY user.name ' +
    'RETURN DISTINCT user.userId, user.username, user.name ' +
    'SKIP {skip} LIMIT {limit}';
```

You can even narrow it further:

```
  let queryString = 'MATCH (user:User ' + (userId ? '{userId:{userId}}' : '') + ') ' +
    'WHERE ((user.username =~ {name}) OR (user.name =~ {name})) ' +
    'WITH user ' +
    'ORDER BY user.name ' +
    'RETURN DISTINCT user.userId, user.username, user.name ' +
    'SKIP {skip} LIMIT {limit}';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, The first one is exactly what I want, But the second one is a bit different from the concept of the `cypher query`, also I could solve it by separating the `if` and `else` like this: ```const userIdOrName = (userId) ?
  'MATCH (user:User {userId:{userId}}) ':
  'MATCH (user:User) ' +
  'WHERE ((user.username =~ {name}) OR (user.name =~ {name})) '; ``` and then 
```let queryString = userIdOrName +
  'WITH user ' +
  'ORDER BY user.name ' +
  'RETURN DISTINCT user.userId, user.username, user.name ' +
  'SKIP {skip} LIMIT {limit}';``` But your answer is what I want.

Comment: I had some `{}` problems in the 2nd one, I think I fixed it.